# Iterate an NSArray in a DoWhile Condition

Tags: loops, sprite-kit, do-while, skspritenode

I have an NSArray, with the names of SKSpriteNodes I add to my scene. They're NSString.

I'm generating a random CGPoint everytime an nstimer is triggered, so that the next sprite's position is generated. I'm using the below code:

```
-(CGPoint) newLocationForPurpose{
    //
    CGFloat randomX,randomY,xMax,xMin,yMax,yMin;
    CGFloat halfSize;
    halfSize= 20.f;
    xMax = self.frame.size.width-halfSize;
    xMin =halfSize;
    yMax = self.frame.size.height-halfSize;
    yMin = halfSize;

    randomX = [[SharedInfo sharedManager] randomFloatBetween:xMin and:xMax];
    randomY = [[SharedInfo sharedManager] randomFloatBetween:yMin and:yMax];

    return CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);

}
```

However, I want to check if the point is in a previously drawn sprite.

What I wanted to do is this:

```
do {
    randomX = [[SharedInfo sharedManager] randomFloatBetween:xMin and:xMax];
    randomY = [[SharedInfo sharedManager] randomFloatBetween:yMin and:yMax];
} while (
         ! for (NSString *name in alreadyIngame) {
    SKNode *node = [self childNodeWithName:name];
    CGRectContainsPoint(node.frame, CGPointMake(randomX, randomY));
}
         );
```

Now, I know my Condition part (the bracket after while) is not working, but that's the kind of thing I want to do. It will go through every string in alreadyInGame array (it will be around 2-3 nodes everytime, there won't be many), and check if the newly generated point is in any previously made sprite.

I was thinking about making the loop first, but it is not really efficient. I could have a boolean, and if the result of the loop is false (i.e. point exist in the array) to do the randomisation again.

Is there any other way in your opinion?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do it:

```
CGFloat randomX, randomY;
BOOL unique = NO;
do {
    randomX = [[SharedInfo sharedManager] randomFloatBetween:xMin and:xMax];
    randomY = [[SharedInfo sharedManager] randomFloatBetween:yMin and:yMax];
    unique = YES;
    for (NSString *name in alreadyInGame) {
        SKNode *node = [self childNodeWithName:name];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(node.frame, CGPointMake(randomX, randomY))) {
            unique = NO;
            break;
        }
    }
} while (!unique);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. One general question, do you think it's better to have the for... In a separate method, and call it from within the do while?

Comment: @Septronic I would only do that if I used the code somewhere else, otherwise it achieves nothing.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I was thinking something in line of a  class or something to handle related methods, like a combiner class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.